# invoke-expression inside scriptblock of invoke-command not working

Tags: powershell

I've got the following script

```
$name = (Invoke-Command -ComputerName "STW111" -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock { Invoke-Expression "C:\PSS\User Tool\UserTool.exe"} -AsJob).Name

Wait-Job -Name $name
```

This not working, however, if I move the usertool to c:\pss\, it works fine.

```
$name = (Invoke-Command -ComputerName "STW111" -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock { Invoke-Expression "C:\PSS\UserTool.exe"} -AsJob).Name

Wait-Job -Name $name
```

I really need to get to grips with escaping in Powershell.

Any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
Invoke-Expression "& 'C:\PSS\User Tool\UserTool.exe'"
```